# Scale of designing an IP Geolocation Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, geolocation, ip, scale

just a bit of background. I'm quite new to software development so am not very good at assessing how big a project is. Recently, I've been asked to look into how to Geolocate an IP Address without using any existing databases.

I looked through some research papers and learned a bit about delay-based Geolocation Techniques. It seems if I want to implement an IP Address without using an existing database, I would basically need to:

1) Get access to a bunch of different servers I know the physical location of and be able to send pings with them to a bunch of other servers I know the location of and the target IP Address

2) Compare the delays I received from the servers I know the location of with the target IP address to get the best match

It seems to me that this is quite a massive project to setup, though there's a bunch of research papers that use these techniques so I'm not sure if the scale is really as big as I'm expecting. Anyways, my main question is that is setting up something like this as big of a problem as I originally suspected or is it actually quite simple if you have the servers available?

Almost every Geolocation related question falls back to using a database and the main reason I'm looking into an algorithm that doesn't is because we already have a database but want this as sort of a backup or validator, and I want to try and figure out if this is worth pursuing.

Comment: Is geographic location even the largest component of latency?

Comment: I'm looking into the same thing, have you made any progress with this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many researches done since 2000 related to this technique. You can search "Topology-based Geolocation" in Google Scholar and read the research papers. You can add value to the research by not reinventing the wheels.